# Пользователь может войти с двух браузеров одновременно - нормально ли это?

Tags: mysql, cookie, сессия, site, login

На моем сайте пользователь может войти и оставаться в системе с двух разных браузеров, правильно ли это и чем это может грозить ? На прошлых проектах мне приходилось реализовывать функцию которая позволяла держать активной только одну сессию от одного пользователя. Есть ли какие либо подводные камни когда пользователь одновременно может входит с разных браузеров ? Нужно ли давать пользователю такую возможность или сессия должна быть только одна?

Comment: Это зависит от ваших личных предпочтений и задач сайта. Большинство сайтов позволяют входить с нескольких браузеров.

Comment: *Нужно ли давать пользователю такую возможность или сессия должна быть только одна?* Почти наверняка нужно. Особенно на случай, когда у юзера упал один браузер, и он вынужден запустить второй - он будет просто счастлив сидеть и ждать, пока сессия ресетнется. А если старую отшибать - он будет счастлив, когда случайно попадёт не в ту ссылку в Избранном, и его сессия в соседнем браузере сдохнет. Да и что у тебя в твоей системе может быть такого, что бы требовало строго одной сессии? В крайнем случае на вторую авторизацию выводи "Один уже есть, кого послать, его или тебя?"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все просто, как "фирма Сэлдом". **Если есть существенная причина** ограничить пользователя всего одной (ну, или как вариант - n) активной сессией - **это нужно делать**. При этом по возможности пользователю давать выбор какую из уже существующих сессий принудительно завершить. Если возможности нет - самостоятельно "глушить" сессию с самой старой последней активностью.

**Если такой существенной причины нет** - нет смысла и в ограничении, **зачем лишний огород городить?**

На практике такое ограничение по активным сессиям я встречал (да и сам писал, чего греха таить) только для ресурсов, предоставляющих доступ на платной основе. Например, платный доступ к видео/аудио архивам, стримам, картам и т.п. Чтобы "халявщики", купив одну подписку на всех, не расшаривали ее на своих сайтах для всех желающих и зарабатывали на рекламе. Как частный случай, встречал ограничение по количеству одновременных сессий для бесплатного доступа к платному сервису. Например, бесплатно можно работать с контентом только с 1 браузера/приставки/телевизора, хочешь с двух одновременно (например, со стационарного компа и с ноутбука или смартфона) - оплати доступ для второй сессии (это имеет смысл, если предоставляется доступ к сервису и в нем есть частное хранилище некоего контента - документов, изображений, файлов и т.п.).

Так что **ответы на Ваши вопросы "*правильно ли это?*" и "*Нужно ли давать пользователю такую возможность или сессия должна быть только одна?*" никто кроме Вас дать не сможет**. Просто потому, что никто из нас не знает нюансов функционирования Вашего сайта. :)

P.S. Если Вас сильно заботит тема безопасности - дайте возможность пользователю в его профиле просмотреть список активных сессий и принудительно завершить их при необходимости.

P.P.S. Вспомнил еще две сферы применения такого подхода к пользовательским сессиям.

- Банковская сфера и финансовые операции.
- Сфера безопасности и доступ к конфиденциальным данным.

Сам в этих областях не писал, но пользовался. :)

P.P.P.S. Иногда имеет смысл ограничивать количество и длительность открытых сессий для определенных категорий пользователей. Например, доступ администратора к админке, кассира/бухгалтера в биллинговой системе, или специалиста по настройке оборудования, работающего удаленно с выездом на территорию клиента. При этом тот же пользователь имеет обычный доступ к основному сайту компани на "общих основаниях" - т.е. без ограничения на количество сессий.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ меня полностью устраивает.

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем, как задавать вопрос по поводу - страшно ли это? Походи по сайтах (любых), и попробуй найти сайт где за два логина (сессии) тебе что-то скажут? Верный ответ: нигде. Никто не боиться этого, т.к. в любом случае, обойти это можно будет всякими VPN-сервисами или же простой сменой прокси-сервера, только лишь усложнишь себе жизнь такой выхоткой.

На счет одновременного логина - то посмотри на Google, у него сотни сайтов используют один аккаунт, и даже в таком случае ему не за что беспокоиться.